# Виртуальный статический метод

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cocos2d

Возникла необходимость переопределения статического метода. Как это возможно реализовать?

UPD:
Необходимо переопределить функцию сцены, иначе происходит инициализация этой сцены, а не наследованной сцены.

```
CCScene* BaseScreen::scene()
{

    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    BaseScreen *layer = BaseScreen::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;   
}
```

UPD: Я лох и пропустил важное объявление в классе

Comment: в с++ нет методов. просто нет. Есть функции класса. Но даже если так, и хочется виртуальную статическую функцию, то их также нет (стандарт 10.3.10 "Nor can a virtual function be a static member, since a virtual function call relies on a specific object for determining which function to invoke."

Comment: Добавьте use case, чего именно вы хотите добиться и с каким синтаксисом. Без этого сложно понять суть вопроса.

Comment: @KoVadim, я встречал в литературе по С++ и термины функции, и функции-члены, и методы, которые синонимичны.

Comment: в книгах "с++ глазами хакера за 24 часа"? То, как некоторые авторы называют, ещё не значит, что это правильно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Виртуальные статические методы не имеют смысла, поскольку `static` означает принадлежность к классу, а не к конкретной сущности этого класса.
- Понятно также, что в следующем `snippet'e` вызовы `instance.X()` и `ObjectWithStaticMethod.X()` эквивалентны:

  ```
  struct ObjectWithStaticMethod
  {
      static void X();
  };

  ObjectWithStaticMethod instance;

  instance.X(); // <------------------ Это одно и то же.
                                               |
  ObjectWithStaticMethod::X(); // <------------
  ```
- В связи с этим, либо используйте обычный виртуальный метод, либо расскажите нам, какую **настоящую задачу** вы решаете.

> (Поскольку в своей постановке вопроса вы сформулировали *опосредованный вывод* о том, что вам нужен `static virtual` метод, не рассказав, как вы пришли к такому заключению)

Comment: +1 за "настоящую задачу".

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот:

```
class A
{
public:
  static int foo() { return 0; }
  virtual int callStatic() { return A::foo(); }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  static int foo() { return 1; }
  int callStatic() { return B::foo(); }
};

int main()
{

  A * a = new B();
  std::cout<<a->callStatic();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А в чем проблема? Переопределяется как обычная функция. Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    static void func() {cout << "A\n";}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    static void func() { cout << "B\n";}
};

int main() {
    A::func();
    B::func();
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
 A
 B
```

Я правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Если только человеку не нужна виртуальность:)

Comment: Насколько я понял нужно вызывать перегруженный статический метод производного класса.

Comment: Виртуальные статические функции не разрешены.

Comment: @KoVadim: как вы представляете себе синтаксис, при котором будет виртуальность? приведёте пример?

Comment: в с++ - никак. Смайлик вроде стоит.
В делфи или смаллтолк, к примеру, пожалуйста.

Comment: Хм, тогда вас не затруднит привести пример на дельфях или смолтоке, в образовательных целях?

Comment: на делфи есть такое понятие как метаклассы. Для некоторых эта тема очень нетривиальна (она просто идет в разрез с другими языками). Классический пример виртуального статического метода - конструктор в делфи. (хоть он и не имеет модификатора static, но его вызывают, когда экземляра ещё нет). Пример можно подглянуть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436961/where-virtual-constructors-are-used).

Смоллтолком в достаточной мере не владею:)

Comment: @KoVadim: спасибо!