# Виртуальная статическая функция

Tags: c++, ооп

Почему статическая функция не может быть виртуальной?

Comment: «Виртуальные статические методы не имеют смысла, поскольку static означает принадлежность к классу, а не к конкретной сущности этого класса» — цитата [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/192580/227016).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Интересный вопрос.

Ведь статическая функция — это та, которая не принимает указатель (`this`) на конкретный экземпляр класса, а потому работает исключительно с тем, что принадлежит самому классу (то есть объявлено с ключевым словом `static`).

В то же время, виртуальная функция отличается от обычного метода исключительно своим присутствием в таблице виртуальных функций (`vtable`).

То есть **технически ничто не мешает поместить статическую (да и вообще любую) функцию в `vtbl`** — это же просто константный массив указателей на функции. Единственное, что изменится для компилятора — пропадание необходимости передавать первым аргументом указатель `this` некоторым виртуальным функциям.

**Но тогда возникает идеологическое противоречие.** С одной стороны, статическая функция принадлежит самому классу (неважно какому — базовому или наследнику), а потому не требует знания `this`. С другой, виртуальность привязана к конкретному экземпляру класса, а потому требует этот указатель. Получаем противоречие: для поиска класса `this` нужен, а для вызова нет. Какой-то полустатический метод получается.

Поэтому комитет постановил: подобные финты в языке не разрешать.

Answer (score 2):

Специфика и сущность виртуального метода заключается в том, то выбор конкретной версии виртуального метода делается в момент вызова на основе анализа *динамического типа* объекта, использованного в этом вызове, в левой части операторов `->`, `.`, `->*` или `.*`.

Статические методы - это фактически обычные функции, которые вызываются без участия каких-либо объектов. Поэтому и анализ динамического типа там применять не к чему.